# How to cal function name to other service id in jasmine karma

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Below is my ctrl file code and i'm calling this into jasmine spec file.When i run the spec file i'm getting the below error
TypeError:undefined is not object

```js
id = myservice.functionname(otherservice)[0].id;
```

Comment: Code in unsufficient to come to any conclusions nor give you any answer. Please post more of the relevant code to your problem. From this alone, I'd say that `myservice` is `undefined`.

Comment: Hey sorry for inconvenient my code.I inject(myservice&otherservice) in my spec file .In my ctrl file if i put   id = '25' like this it is working on my spec file if i put this one id = myservice.functionname(otherservice)[0].id;  .It is getting error like  this "TypeError:undefined is not object<evaluating 'myservice.functionName(otherservice)[0].id'>".

Comment: I don't know karma nor jasmine, but it seems like the index `0` of `myservice.functionname(otherservice)` doesn't exist.